# Is there any way I can tell whether increase in total energy in molecular dynamics simulation is due to large time step or not?

Tags: computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

Does increase due to large time step has any type of signature that will tell for certain (or almost certainly) that that is the reason?

Comment: Exponential increase in total energy with time gives a hint (but can also be due to errors in the eqations), more stable integration schemes tend to have oscillatory behaviour of the total energy.

Comment: Any increase or decrease in energy is due to you using the wrong (non-symplectic) integrator. A correct numerical treatment does not suffer from this problem and it will also keep the total momentum and angular momentum conserved.

Comment: @CuriousOne But won't numerical errors will still occur, changing the energy slightly (and thus for a stable integrator the energy will oscillate)?

Comment: @SebastianRiese: The symplectic integrators will greatly reduce the problem, but I would go one step further and calculate the total energy, momentum and angular momentum of the system either every time step or ever n-th time step and use any deviations from the initial conditions to correct the momenta of all particles accordingly, so that the average of these quantities stays constant in time. The values should not oscillate, otherwise the numerics introduces a new timescale. Ideally, the fluctuations have a white noise spectrum, otherwise I would be concerned.

Comment: @Sebastian For velocity-verlet algorithm, if properly implemented, can increase in total energy be attributed to large time step? (I am using perfectly elastic reflective boundary conditions)

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert on numerics. I just know the very basics. But I believe, that a growing energy most likely points to another problem. Idea for experimental verification: reduce the time-step and compare the results.